# How to display the symbol dollar $ correctly?

Tags: listings, minted, xml, java

I have a minted block as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

    \begin{listing}[ht]
    \begin{minted}{xml}

    <plugin>
      <groupId>maven.plugin</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
      <configuration>   
        <tipo>\${env.TEST}</tipo>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>xxxx</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>xxx</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>

    \end{minted}
    \caption{Maven plugin XML code}
    \label{pomsinau}
    \end{listing}

\end{document}
```

I am using the escape bar `\` to the symbol of dollar `$`, but the latex is displaying the symbol `$` along with the escape character in the output:

How do I remove the escape bar at the output and leave only the symbol `$`?

[image]

Comment: In “verbatim” environments you don't need to escape special characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use `$`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

    \begin{listing}[ht]
    \begin{minted}{xml}

    <plugin>
      <groupId>maven.plugin</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
      <configuration>   
        <tipo>${env.TEST}</tipo>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>xxxx</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>xxx</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>

    \end{minted}
    \caption{Maven plugin XML code}
    \label{pomsinau}
    \end{listing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank​ you so much for your help Gonzalo Medina, now it's all working!